# How to fetch content from a webpage?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to fetch div content from a webpage and to use it in my page.

I have the url http://www.freebase.com/search?limit=30&start=0&query=cancer
I want to fetch div content with id artilce-1001. How can I do that in php or jQuery?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use PHP, you may want to have a look at [Simple HTML DOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/). It is a nice single include file. The [docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) give an example of scraping slashdot as:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://slashdot.org/');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('div.article') as $article) {
    $item['title']     = $article->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['intro']    = $article->find('div.intro', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('div.details', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}
```

Regex is never any good at (and should never be used for) parsing HTML. It isn't regular, and you end up with huge regular expressions for what would be simple in jQuery or the above library

**EDIT:**
So you would want to use something like

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.freebase.com/search?limit=30&start=0&query=cancer');
$text = $html->find('div[id=artilce-1001]',0)->plaintext;
```

Comment: That Simple HTML DOM will make me change my last project:) For the better:) Thanks:)

Comment: @Antonio: If you like **Simple HTML DOM**, check phpQuery: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/  . The project is actually supported.

Answer (score 2):

If this really is about a [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) topic and not about getting HTML from a website in general, using the [API](http://www.freebase.com/docs/web_services) and getting familiar with [MQL](http://www.freebase.com/docs/mql) should be the better solution since that would allow you to restrict your search in specific types easily.

Example:

```
[{
  "/common/topic/article": {
    "guid":     null,
    "limit":    1,
    "optional": true
  },
  "/common/topic/image": {
    "id":       null,
    "limit":    1,
    "optional": true
  },
  "id":     null,
  "name":   null,
  "name~=": "*Cancer*",
  "type":   "/user/radiusrs/default_domain/astrological_sign"
}]​
```

Can be passed to [mqlread](http://www.freebase.com/docs/web_services/mqlread) [directly](http://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?query=%7B%22query%22%3A%5B%7B%22%2Fcommon%2Ftopic%2Farticle%22%3A%7B%22guid%22%3Anull%2C%22limit%22%3A1%2C%22optional%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22%2Fcommon%2Ftopic%2Fimage%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22limit%22%3A1%2C%22optional%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22name%22%3Anull%2C%22name%7E%3D%22%3A%22%2ACancer%2A%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22%2Fuser%2Fradiusrs%2Fdefault_domain%2Fastrological_sign%22%7D%5D%7D) and returns a JSON list with possible matches for the astrological sign "Cancer". Then, you can simply get the article and image by using [trans_raw](http://www.freebase.com/docs/web_services/trans_raw) and/or [trans_blurb](http://www.freebase.com/docs/web_services/trans_blurb), if you need to. :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you'll probably want to GET the page (probably using CURL or similar) then you'll have to parse the html, which is probably not the easiest thing to do, but I'm guessing there are libraries out there to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
$("#LoadIntoThisDiv").load("http://www.freebase.com/search?limit=30&start=0&query=cancer #artilce-1001");
```

There is an example like this on the jQuery site [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback)

Comment: Will that work on a domain other than the one the page is served from?

I'm thinking not.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.freebase.com/search?limit=30&start=0&query=cancer');

$match = preg_match("#id=\"article-1001\".*</div>#", $content, $matches);
```

Regular expression probably won't work, but it's example or direction you can use, just play with it :)

Comment: that regex wouldn't work for the sample given - the div is on multiple lines, and the .* is too greedy

Comment: Actually .* means all chars except new line, so that's why it won't work, because expression will be terminated after div is closed.
Besides that, I learned in the past that parsing HTML is one of the hardest parts ...
Anyway, I gave him an example, still he should put some effort into it ;)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side, jQuery is client side so it really depends on what you want to achieve. Also note that because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you generally can't perform an Ajax request to another domain via javascript anyway (but you could proxy it via your own server)

jQuery aside, here's a simple way to do it in PHP, which will work for the case you provide

```
$url="http://www.freebase.com/search?limit=30&start=0&query=cancer";
$html=file_get_contents($url);

if (preg_match('{<div id="article-1001".*?>(.*?)</div>}s', $html, $matches))
{
    $content=$matches[1];
}
```

Note the 's' modifier, which makes . match newlines, and the .*? idiom, which makes the matching the inner part non-greedy so that it only eats up the next `</div>`

This works for your case, but regexes are generally ill suited to this task. You could load the HTML into a [DOmDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and access it that way.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$div=$doc->getElementById("article-1001");
```