# Getting Website URL Dynamically in Simple PHP HTML dom parser

Tags: php, variables

This script will get a website address dynamically from the url.
Example: `www.site.com/fetch.php?url=http://www.google.com` to fetch its(google.com) content using php simple html dom parser but my script cant get the url .. any idea>

```
$url = htmlentities($_GET['url']);
$html = file_get_html('$url')->plaintext;
$result = $html;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not quote the `$url` variable:

```
$url = "htmlentities($_GET['url'])";
$html = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;
$result = $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure use can this `$html=file_get_contents($_GET['url']);`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `file_get_contents($_GET['url'])` as suggested or CURL

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$_GET['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
?>
```

To get the plaintext , you need to do some parsing . You can get it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124235/how-to-fetch-content-from-a-webpage?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Added a link where you can get some useful stuffs . Comment if you have problem in implementing what that link suggests.